# Call method post transaction commit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, auditing

I have a very peculiar requirement where I have to insert records in 2 tables (audit tables) if insertion in one particular table succeeds. Here **I am not talking about @PreInsert in Listener** because Listeners are always called in the same transaction. I know that can be done manually by simply calling "save" method after the first save succeeds. BUT I wanted to know is there any other way which I can try using Listener be it JPA/EclipseLink/String-data so that future developers of the application are not forced to insert data in audit table manually.

Basically I am looking for @PostCommit type of functionality. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you ultimately **do** want the callback to run within the boundary of your current transaction, you just want it to run *after* Hibernate has done its things, just like Hibernate Envers works.

To do this, you basically need to register an event action queue callback like the following:

```
session.getActionQueue().registerProcess(
  new BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess() {
    @Override
    public void doBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImplementor session) {
      // do whatever you want with the session here.
    }
  }
);
```

If you ultimately must run your code **outside** the transaction, you could do something similar:

```
session.getActionQueue().registerProcess(
  new AfterTransactionCompletionProcess() {
    @Override
    public void doAfterTransactionCompletion(boolean success, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
      // do whatever you want with the session here.
    }
  }
);
```

That should get you going either way.